# Remove Arrow buttons from JScrollBar in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

JButton:

```
 public class noButton extends JButton
    {
        //tried getPreferredSize() and getSize() too
        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() 
        {          
            return new Dimension();
        }
    }
```

Custom UI:

```
public class barUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {
    barUI()
    {
    }
    protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int i) {
        return new noButton();
    }
    protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int i){
        return new noButton();
    }
    @Override
    protected void installComponents() {
        switch(this.scrollbar.getOrientation()) {
            case 0:
                if (this.scrollbar.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {
                    this.incrButton = this.createIncreaseButton(3);
                    this.decrButton = this.createDecreaseButton(7);
                } else {
                    this.incrButton = this.createIncreaseButton(7);
                    this.decrButton = this.createDecreaseButton(3);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                this.incrButton = this.createIncreaseButton(5);
                this.decrButton = this.createDecreaseButton(1);
        }
        this.incrButton=new noButton();
        this.decrButton=new noButton();
        this.decrButton.setSize(0,0);
        this.scrollbar.add(incrButton);
        this.scrollbar.add(decrButton);
        System.out.println(incrButton.getParent());
        System.out.println(incrButton.getSize());
        this.scrollbar.setEnabled(this.scrollbar.isEnabled());
    }
}
```

ScrollPane:

```
scroll=new JScrollPane(){
            @Override
            public void updateUI(){
                super.updateUI();
                getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new barUI());
                getHorizontalScrollBar().setUI(new barUI());
            }
        };
```

I've been trying to remove one button first. The above code was suggested in various threads but it does absolutely nothing. I just get the default looking button resized by the `vertical.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));`

There was another suggestion to override the method that adds the buttons and remove the relevant lines.. that too did nothing..

Update : Added 'Arrow' to the question for clarification
Update : Changes to the code

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the buttons? The point of using a JScrollPane is to allow the user to scroll the data. If there are no buttons, then the user can't scroll the data. If they can't scroll the data then why use a JScrollPane?

Comment: I just wanna remove the arrow buttons... and possibly add transpaency .. The scrolling thumb will still be there and Mouse wheel works

Answer (score 0):

> There was another suggestion to override the method that adds the buttons and remove the relevant lines.

Seems to work OK like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollBarUI;

public class RemoveArrowButtonsTest {
  private Component makeUI() {
    UIManager.put("ScrollBar.incrementButtonGap", 0);
    UIManager.put("ScrollBar.decrementButtonGap", 0);
    String txt = String.join("\n", Collections.nCopies(100, "1234567890"));
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(txt)));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(txt)) {
      @Override public void updateUI() {
        super.updateUI();
        getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new WithoutArrowButtonScrollBarUI());
        getHorizontalScrollBar().setUI(new WithoutArrowButtonScrollBarUI());
      }
    });
    return p;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new RemoveArrowButtonsTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class ZeroSizeButton extends JButton {
  @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension();
  }
}

class WithoutArrowButtonScrollBarUI extends MetalScrollBarUI {
  @Override protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
    return new ZeroSizeButton();
  }

  @Override protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
    return new ZeroSizeButton();
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope ... did not do anything at all. Creating custom UI classes doesnt seem to be able to change anything other than the isEnabled property. I tried fiddling with other stuff to such as not adding the Buttons or adding "ZeroSizeButtons" in installComponents() but the result is always the exact same (as it originally was).